# Android Studio does not import dependency from jCenter or Maven Central

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

There is a very weird issue that I cannot explain. I have a library in both [jCenter](http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/kostasdrakonakis/spinner-preference/) and [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.kostasdrakonakis%7Cspinner-preference%7C1.0.0%7Cpom) accessible like this:

```
implementation 'com.github.kostasdrakonakis:spinner-preference:1.0.0'
```

or for Gradle < 3.0

```
compile 'com.github.kostasdrakonakis:spinner-preference:1.0.0'
```

I added it as a dependency in my Project in Android Studio and it does not download it.

My app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(includes: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.github.kostasdrakonakis:spinner-preference:1.0.0'
    api project(':databasemanager')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
}
```

My build.gradle for root project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```

The external libraries:

[image]

Any Ideas what is happening?

Comment: Your dependency seems to work for me. What do you see if you right click your project -> Open Module Settings -> select Dependencies tab?

Comment: You can see it in your project fine?

Comment: @nicobatu I see normally the dependency as maven but still in my project is not recognised in the classes

Comment: I see, the import is not working. Is it perhaps an issue with how you uploaded your library?

Comment: I see the files are available in jcenter though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to have `<packaging>` type to be `pom` inside your `.pom` file?

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/kostasdrakonakis/spinner-preference/1.0.0/spinner-preference-1.0.0.pom

http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/kostasdrakonakis/spinner-preference/1.0.0/:spinner-preference-1.0.0.pom

Typically I would expect this to be `aar`.

Comment: how to add as aar?

Comment: In your maven deploy script, you can specify the `packaging` type: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sec:maven_pom_generation

For example:
`packaging 'aar'`

Comment: I fixed it now but still not seeing improvement

Comment: It seems to be working after clearing gradle cache. Thanks for POM instructions.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove `mavencentral()` from your gradle build and just use `jcenter()`.

This issue happened to me. It won't download any dependencies and gets stuck syncing with gradle files. I believe the issue comes from Android Studio not knowing which link to grab the dependency from. You should have one or the other and not both.

Comment: JCenter will be shutting down, all need to migrate on MavenCentral